# How do I add (sum) individual radio button groups?

Tags: javascript

I have programmed an online assessment which can calculate the total score and display it as a percentage. However, each of the questions pertain to different categories and I would like to be able to calculate and show the results for the different categories.

Example: I need to sum radio buttons 1, 9, 17, 25 & 33 for the "career" category and display the result in the "career" category text field in the results box at the bottom of the page. I have 8 categories and don't want to put all the questions for each category together because the person taking the assessment will figure out how it's calculated and might manipulate it to get a higher score. I have googled so many alternatives and they only show adding(sum) radio buttons consecutively. Please can someone help me with the code for this as I have no clue and have spent 2 days trying to figure it out.

Comment: How can we "help [you] with the code" when you haven't shown any? [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Give us _something_ to work with.

Comment: Can you post a link to the web page and/or edit your question to include a sample of the HTML? That would both provide context for your question and allow for more complete examples in the answers.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function total(frm) {
  var tot=0;
  for(var i=0; i<frm.elements.length; i++) {
    if(frm.elements[i].type=="checkbox" || frm.elements[i].type=="radio") {
      if(frm.elements[i].checked) tot+=Number(frm.elements[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("totalDiv").firstChild.data=tot*4/8+"%";
}
</script>

Comment: Hi Abdul, thius site won't let me put in the entire script - it's quite big as the assessment has 40 questions. The link to the web page is http://www.creditincontrol.co.za/final.php. Please can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the name property of the radio button, you must add the category name. (eg. radiogroup23career)

Then make a hidden input field in your page for each category.

Have a logic in your javascript to add up each button by category(a part of the name field).  $('input[name*="career"]').val(); (JQuery to search for an element by a part of the name)

Then set the hidden input field with that value.

Then do a form post, preserving the current results in the hidden fields.

Do the same on page 2 just make sure to add the results to the results posted from the previous page.

Hope this helps,
pH

See more details below:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1career" value="1">Milk<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1career" value="2" checked>Butter<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1career" value="3">Cheese
<input type="hidden" name = "currentcareertotal">
```

And in your JQuery do as follows
    Loop through all your:
    $('input[name*="career"]').val()  items.

and add them up to a var named "careertotal"
set that value to your hidden field.

```
$('input[name="currentcareertotal"]').val(careertotal);
```

Comment: If I change the group buttons from radio1, radio9, radio17, radio25 & radio33 name=radio1 to name=career - won't this effect the user clicking on the radio buttons on the website? There are 8 categories and 40 radio groups...

Comment: Thanks a million....I think I know how to set a hidden input field for each category.....do I insert it at the top of each radio button group or as a list at the bottom? How do I get the answer to show in the text box at the bottom of the page "results" table?

Comment: Thanks HarHaHu....do I put that same script at the bottom of each career radio group? And then how do I get the total to show in the bottom table in the career results text box?

Comment: That script could really go anywhere as long as it is triggered on the form post.  Use a Javascript to toggle the display of a label during an onchange event.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your advice.... I just need to know one more thing... how do I get the result of "career" to show in the career text box at the bottom of the page : http://www.creditincontrol.co.za/final.php

Comment: Hi HarHaHu, thanks for all the help you gave me. I'm going back top the drawing board to implement the changes you have advised. Thanks again for all your help - greatly appreciated.

Comment: The onchange event of a textbox, or the click event of a check current score button, something of that sort.  Happy Programming!